# Local offline development with Firestore

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

Is there any way to use the gcloud firestore emulator to do local offline development when using the web client SDK? (ie client-side JS).

I've found both

`firebase serve --only firestore`
and
`gcloud beta emulators firestore start`

but not sure of intended use cases of either, as the documentation doesn't give much to go on?

Comment: Currently, the primary intended use case is to programmatically test your security rules.  The emulators are going to improve in the future.  https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/test-rules-emulator

Comment: Thanks @DougStevenson - can you clarify what the difference between the two emulators are, or are they just different entry points to the same thing? (https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/beta/emulators/firestore/ vs https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/test-rules-emulator) thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The emulator functionality has improved significantly since I posted this question. The documentation is here now: https://firebase.google.com/docs/emulator-suite