# Running integration & browser tests for Firestore

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm hoping to run integration and cypress browser tests against my React app that uses Firestore. There's a local emulator, but it only is targeted at testing security rules right now (see [Local offline development with Firestore](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55673787/local-offline-development-with-firestore#comment98040869_55673787)).

I can point the tests at a 'development' instance of the database, but that doesn't work if I want to run this in CI across all open pull requests.

In other worlds I’d just create a fresh database and drop it afterwards, but you can only have one firestore database per google cloud project.

Do you prefix the table names everywhere? Automate creating new google projects and dropping them again? Something else obvious I'm missing?

Comment: Running massive amounts of integration tests against actual database instances sounds problematic.  I'd hold off on this and wait for the Firebase team to publish a Firestore emulator that you can run locally.

Comment: @DougStevenson Do you know if this feature will be somehow available this year?